# Cálculo para dias dos meses (calendário)

Tags: javascript

Tenho um array que contém todos os meses do ano. Quero criar um calendário.

```
var meses= new Array("Janeiro","Fevereiro","Marco","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto","Septembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro");
```

Com este array, como fazer para os diferentes dias dos meses, e para o mês de fevereiro.

Comment: Não entendi onde você quer chegar.

Comment: Distingir os meses com os seus dias, para poder apresentar numa tabela. No caso de fevereiro, ou 28 ou 29 dias.

Comment: Ainda não entendi, mas você quer um *array* com o total de dias de cada mês? Algo assim? `var ultimoDiaMeses= new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);`. Teria que fazer uma verificação de bissexto para usar 28 ou 29 dias para fevereiro. Não consigo imaginar o que seja esses 27 dias que você falou.

Comment: Sim tenho um ciclo for para mostar todos os meses até o fim do array (meses.length). Agora que condiçao para mostrar os dias de casa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```js
var meses = new Array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Marco", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Septembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");

function diasDoAno() {
    var ano = $('#ano').val();
    var dias = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
        var diasNoMes = new Date(ano, x + 1, 0).getDate();
        dias[x] = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= diasNoMes; i++) {
            dias[x].push(i);
        }
    }
    var resultado = $('#resultado');
    dias.forEach(function (mes, i) {
        var div = $('<div />').addClass('mes');
        div.append(meses[i]);
        var subDiv = $('<div />').addClass('dias');
        mes.forEach(function (dia) {
            subDiv.append(dia);
        });
        div.append(subDiv);
        resultado.append(div);
    });
}


$('button').on('click', diasDoAno);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Insira ano: <input type="text" id="ano"/>
<button>Mostrar dias</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Esta função tem duas partes. A primeira cria uma array com 12 meses, cada elemento da array com os dias desse mês.

Para saber quantos dias cada mês tem usei `var diasNoMes = new Date(ano, x + 1, 0).getDate();` e depois usei esse valor para fazer um loop interno que insere cada dia na array dos dias.

A segunda parte é para mostrar no HTML. No fundo é a mesma coisa, 2 loops para iterar os dias todos.

Deixo a parte de usar a array que a primeira parte cria para você.

Comment: Estou tentar usar a sua funçao, dos dias dos meses. Quero mostar numa tabela todos os meses com os seus dias. http://jsfiddle.net/h4Lc723t/

Comment: @akm http://jsfiddle.net/h4Lc723t/1/ - faltava só no jsFiddle mudar para `no-wrap` no menu.

Comment: Certo, mas os meses aparecem todos ate ao dia 31.

Comment: @akm não vejo o meu código no seu jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h4Lc723t/2/ adicionei o ciclo for dos dias dos meses